# Proof of Jensen's inequality without the use of induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like to see the proof of the following identity without the use of induction.

For a real convex function $f$, numbers $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ in its domain, and positive weights $a_i$, Jensen's inequality can be stated as:

$$f\left( \frac { \sum { { a }_{ i }{ x }_{ i } }  }{ \sum { { a }_{ j } }  }  \right) \le \frac { { a }_{ i }f({ x }_{ i }) }{ \sum { { a }_{ j } }}$$

PS: I would like to see a derivation rather than the proof. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your starting definition of a convex function ? If it is based on the valuations of the function between two endpoints, induction is unavoidable.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the statement as given? For, say, $n=2$, $x_1=0$, $x_2=1$, $a_1=a_2=1/2$, you are claiming $f(1/2)\le(1/2)f(0)$, which seems unlikely to be true for all convex $f$.

Comment: @ Yves Daoust : Can you please explain, what do you mean here? How did you reach to the conclusion that Induction is unavoidable in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the proof of the general Jensen inequality in probability (proof 2 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Proof_2_.28measure-theoretic_form.29)).